# How to close Launcher web view in flutter/dart

Tags: dart, flutter

My question is how to close the launcher view after creating it ?

```
 urlLauncher(String url) async {
      if (await canLaunch(url)) {
        await launch(url, forceWebView: true);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $url';
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for that 
This pull request adds the closeWebView method, so that the web view can be closed programmatically. To use the version of the pull request, use this in pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  url_launcher:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/flutter/plugins.git
      path: packages/url_launcher
      ref: 2c56dd4cca2f5b85619eaea425baccb1e0600886
```

check your indentations in the yaml files as it is very important..

Comment: Is there any way to hide the url in safari, Tried everything but in IOS it shows URL

Comment: @SarthakSolanki Did you open a question for that?

Comment: Was this ever merged?

Comment: @SuperCode I think it is .